# dying，Installing Hive，an error was reported

Tags: hive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QqNB.png)

I tried several times. After decompressing the compressed package on centos7 and adding the file path, an error occurred when running the hive command. I don’t know which step went wrong.The first time I installed hive, an error was reported. I really can’t find the reason. Can someone please help?